# PHP max_input_time ignored

Tags: php, digital-ocean

using `phpinfo()` I made changes to the correct PHP.ini file.  I adjusted the max_input_time and max_execution_time to 300;  When running phpinfo() again I see max_execution_time worked but max_input_time is still at 60.  Changing this value directly in PHP also does nothing.

PHP 5.6.7-1 on Digitial Ocean

Comment: pasting your php.ini may be help?

Comment: Perhaps digital-ocean does NOT allow that specific property to be changed?

Comment: Did you restart apache to apply the new INI settings?

Answer (score 0):

it Seems restarting php5-fpm did the trick.  Previously I was just restarting my web server.